# Unique PHP on each Page

Tags: php, pages

I'm currently deciding whether or not to use WordPress or write my own code for a future website but I need to know one thing before I can make my final decision.

Is it possible, with WordPress, to insert PHP scripts into a single page. About 40% of my pages will have their own PHP script behind it and I need to know if such a thing is possible (and if so, what I should be looking at).

Thanks.

Comment: yes thats possible. there are plenty of good plugins out there wich can provide that.
e.g.: https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/

Answer (score 1):

Rather than insert PHP scripts into each page what you could do is execute PHP scripts using action [`hooks`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks) with conditional tags or modify the default output of an existing function using a filter hook with [`conditional tag`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) for each page.

You could also create template tags or write your own functions in a separate file and execute on any page in a custom function with conditional tag using the page I.D.

**Filter Example**

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'execute_before_content' ); 

function execute_before_content( $content ) { 

if ( is_singular('page') && function_exists('your_function')) {

    $before_content = your_function();

    $content = $before_content . $content;

    }

return $content;
}
```

**Action Hook Example:**

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'your_function' );
function your_function() {
if ( is_page('007') && function_exists('your_template_tag')): 
        your_template_tag();
endif; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every page can use it's own individual template if needed, have a look at the wordpress template heirarchy image for a bit more info. Basically a page will default to using page.php but if you provide page-{slug}.php where {slug} is the slug of the page, it will use that template instead.

So it's entirely feasible to have a separate 'page' file for each and every page, with code specific to that page on it.

Additionally, if some of the code is shared between multiple pages, just set up a custom page template and assign that template to those pages that use it.

Wordpress template heirarchy: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on the use-case? As Brad stated, using hooks is the the best method to accomplish this functionally. You probably would want to create a plugin that you could maintain, upgrade and reuse... especially if this is for a client!

http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: Hi Tonymazz, this should be a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Sorry new here, absolutely right.